# Magento2 php7.0-memcached Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: magento2, session, memcached, php-7

Need help configuring Magento2 to use memcached for session storage on Ubuntu 16.04 running PHP7.0.4 FPM with php7.0-memcached build from php-memcached-dev github. I wonder what went wrong this time. :D

From phpinfo:

```
memcached support enabled
Version 3.0.0b1
```

My env.php:

```
'session' =>
   array (
      'save' => 'memcached’,
      'save_path' => 'localhost:11211',
),
```

I always get this error when following Magento2 docs to configure Magento2 to use memcached in app/etc/env.php:

```
stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'save_path' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
```

References:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache_magento.html
- https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not memcached, but a small typo in your code:

```
'session' =>
   array (
      'save' => 'memcached ⇨’⇦,
      'save_path' => 'localhost:11211',
),
```

You used a single quote `'` at the beginning of the `memcached` string and and an acute accent `´` at the end.

That's the reason for the PHP parse error.

Comment: Hi @AndreasKoch, thanks for pointing that out. Fix the ` did it! :D